# Label com cursor rato

Tags: javascript

Criei uma label com a posição do cursor, quero que essa label esteja sempre agarrada cm o cursor. Criei isto, funciona, mas não atras do cursor.

```
var x = ev.clientX;
var y = ev.clientY;
var info_souris = document.getElementById("position_souris");
info_souris.innerHTML = x + "," + y; 


<label id="position_souris"></label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um callback para o evento `mousemove`, experimente:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;

    var info_souris = document.getElementById("position_souris");
    info_souris.innerHTML = x + "," + y; 
    info_souris.style.top = y + 'px';
    info_souris.style.left = x + 'px';
  });
};
```

```css
label#position_souris {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<label id="position_souris">aqui</label>
```

Comment: Certo, mas queria que a label estive sempre a atras do cursor.

Comment: Ahhh sim, entendi, espera ai então

Comment: É isso que vc quer? Olhe minha edição @akm

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado